# como colocar a data local na pagina web

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer uma pagina que mostre a data e a hora mas só estou conseguindo colocar a hora alguem pode me dizer como faço para colocar a data. Queria colocar a data no h1 assim como fiz na hora mas não estou conseguindo

```js
var a = setInterval(myTimer);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("tempo").innerHTML = time;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: orangered;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 60%;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <h1 class='tempo' id='tempo'></h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 class='tempo' id='data'></h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Só uma dica, quando for colocar a data, procure trazer essa data de alguma linguagem backend, porque a data do javascript é definida pelo navegador do usuário, ou seja, não é confiável... Uma forma simples de resolver isso é passando `var variavel_date_backend = 'AQUI VC PEGA DO BACKEND'` no `new Date(variavel_date_backend)`;

Comment: É sempre importante postar apenas um [mcve] focado no problema que está tendo. Postagens estilo helpdesk ou com código muito específico não são adequadas para o modelo do site. Para entender e aproveitar melhor o site, é interessante uma lida no [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70). Isto pode ajudar muito na formulação das próximas de maneira à postagem ser útil para um público amplo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp

```js
var a = setInterval(myTimer);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  var data = d.toLocaleDateString()
  document.getElementById("tempo").innerHTML = time;
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: orangered;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 60%;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <h1 class='tempo' id='tempo'></h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 class='tempo' id='data'></h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure a apresentação da data do jeito que quiser!

`toLocaleTimeString()` - string apenas de hora no formato localizado do seu sistema

O método `Get` serve para leitura de partes da informação de data e hora armazenadas no objeto date.

`getDay()` - Dia da semana

`getDate()` - dia dentro do mês

`getFullYear()` - ano - 1970 .......

```js
var a = setInterval(myTimer);

function myTimer() {
  //horário
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = time;

//dia da semana e data

//nesse array você escreve os dias como quiser
var dia_semana=new Array("Domingo","Segunda-feira","Terça-feira","Quarta-feira","Quinta-feira","Sexta-feira","Sabado");

var nome_mes=new Array("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");

//configuração da apresentação
var HOJE = dia_semana[d.getDay()] + ", " + d.getDate() + "/" + nome_mes[d.getMonth()] + "/" + d.getFullYear();

document.getElementById("tempo").innerHTML = HOJE;

}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: orangered;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 60%;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <h1 class='tempo' id='tempo'></h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 class='tempo' id='data'></h1>

</div>
```